# Save Custom Property to Shape Key

Tags: python, scripting, properties, shape-keys

I'm trying to save a StringProperty to the shape keys of an object. In the past I've used `bpy.types.Object` to save Props to an object, and `.Scene` to save it to the scene, but when trying to save it to `.ShapeKey` it isn't treated as a String. When I print() the value of this StringProperty, it gives:

`<_PropertyDeferred, <built-in function StringProperty>, {'default': ''}>`

Why is it 'Deferred', and how can I save properties to individuial shape keys, just as the other shape key properties such as `Range Min` and `Vertex Group` have been?

```
class KEY_LIST_OP_alter_groups(Operator):    
    def execute(self, context): 
        print(context.active_object.active_shape_key.KEY_LIST)

def register():
    bpy.types.ShapeKey.KEY_LIST = StringProperty(default='')
```

When typing into the Console the `'KEY_LIST'` does auto-suggest under `C.active_object.active_shape_key.KEY_LIST()` so it appears to be registering, it's just not being understood as a String.

Comment: Custom properties can only be added to ["any subclass of an `ID`, `Bone` and `PoseBone`"](https://docs.blender.org/api/3.0/bpy.props.html?highlight=enumproperty#assigning-to-existing-classes). [`bpy.types.ShapeKey`](https://docs.blender.org/api/3.0/bpy.types.ShapeKey.html) isn't one of those.

Comment: So is there a way I can do this? There 'are' properties saved to specific shape keys after all.

Comment: Not that I know of. You can try storing data on the `bpy.types.Key` instead.

Comment: This looks promising. But how do I access it? All I can find under context is active_shape_key. I'll keep looking around though.